# trying to save the figure of stacked bar chart in canvas widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

I grouped the data and tried for a stacked bar chart and it worked fine the figure is also plotted in the interpreter with an ipynb jupyter notebook file as show in the picture attached, but when I want to use that figure in the canvas of matplotlib.backends canvas for displaying plots figure was not plotted just empty axes,

need some solution to save the subplot and utilize it for displaying in canvas

can any share their knowledge with me to solve my problem

```
    dfd = df.groupby(['Region','Sub-Category']).aggregate({'Sales':sum}).unstack(-2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(7, 5))
```

[image: 1]

below is the core detailed code

```
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/Excel_files/Sample - Superstore2.xlsx")
  df.groupby(['Category','Sub-Category']).aggregate({'Sales':sum}).unstack(-2).plot(kind = 'bar',stacked= True,figsize = (15,7) )
  plt.show()
```

this is my full code what I want is like I to want use its figure to display in the Tkinter canvas widget, as like we have option in below possible way as far as my knowledge

```
      fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(7, 5))
```

by using ax we will plot graphs and those graphs will be stored in fig variable as subplots and this fig variable can be used to display the figure in canvas.

type of fig varibale is ->  <class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>

but when i use ax for plotting the stacked bar plot its not been plotted properly

Comment: Can you provide more of your code so that others can test it? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.